# Suckerfish drop-down - IE6 & 7 alignment issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, suckerfish

On [this page](http://mcael.missionmedia.net) there is a navigation menu.  I'm using the suckerfish dropdown and i have modified it slightly to incorporate images(top portion of nav; each is an image).

Everything looks & works fine in all modern browsers.  Yet in IE6 & 7 when user mousesovers a nav item the drop downs don't appear right below that nav item, but appear under the next nav item.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add left:0 to your absolute positioned ul's.